# Inverting numpy array image which might be uint8, uint16,

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy

Is there a prettier way to do this? Specifically, are these max values available through the numpy API? I haven't been able to find them in the API, although they are easily found [here in the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html).

```
MAX_VALUES = {np.uint8: 255, np.uint16: 65535, np.uint32: 4294967295, \
              np.uint64: 18446744073709551615}

try:
    image = MAX_VALUES[image.dtype] - image
except KeyError:
    raise ValueError, "Image must be array of unsigned integers."
```

Packages like PIL and cv2 provide convenient tools for inverting an image, but at this point in the code I have a numpy array -- more sophisticated analysis follows -- and I'd like to stick with numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way, you do not need to define `MAX_VALUES` yourself. NumPy [has them built-in](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.iinfo.html#numpy-iinfo):

```
import numpy as np
h, w = 100, 100
image = np.arange(h*w).reshape((h,w)).astype(np.uint8)
max_val = np.iinfo(image.dtype).max
print(max_val)
# 255
image ^= max_val

print(image)
# [[255 254 253 ..., 158 157 156]
#  [155 154 153 ...,  58  57  56]
#  [ 55  54  53 ..., 214 213 212]
#  ..., 
#  [ 27  26  25 ..., 186 185 184]
#  [183 182 181 ...,  86  85  84]
#  [ 83  82  81 ..., 242 241 240]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try doing

```
image ^= MAX_VALUES[image.dtype]
```

Comment: ``^=`` is new to me, and it's difficult to Google. What's the operator called?

Comment: I believe that is the `xor` operator.